# Return more than 1 types from a table using SQL

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I have a table like this

```
Type <- c("TEN_02","TEN_04","TEN_05",
          "JOS_01","JOS_02","JOS_03",
          "VIT_06","VIT_11","VIT_08")
Value <- c(5,8,9,11,8,4,6,6,7)
df <- data.frame(Type,Value)
```

I am trying to use an sql statement to extract any types with TEN & VIT from this table.

I am able to return for one type using sqldf

```
library(sqldf)
df1 <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df
             WHERE Type LIKE 'TEN%'")
```

But, if I need to pass in a variable "TYPES" that has more than one type

```
TYPES <- 'TEN,VIT'

df1 <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df
             WHERE Type LIKE ('",TYPES,"%')")
```

I get an error

```
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  unrecognized token: "'"
```

My desired output is

```
    Type Value
  TEN_02     5
  TEN_04     8
  TEN_05     9
  VIT_06     6
  VIT_11     6
  VIT_08     7
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? I would like to use SQL for this instead of dplyr or data.table since I would want to apply the logic to query databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** First surround each type in `TYPES` with single quotes giving `TYPESQ`. Now from the example in the question it seems that the type is always the part before an underscore in `Type` so extract that part from Type.  (It is also the case that the types in the question are always the first 3 characters of the Type field so if that were always the case then we could simplify further by using `substr(TYPE, 1, 3)` in place of the more complex`substr(...)` expression shown.)  Now use `in` to find a match.  Prefacing `sqldf` with fn$ enables perl-like $ string interpolation in the SQL string so that we can substitute in `TYPESQ` at the appropriate point.

```
TYPESQ <- gsub("\\b", "'", TYPES, perl = TRUE)
sql <- "select * from df where substr(Type, 1, instr(Type, '_') - 1) in ($TYPESQ)"
fn$sqldf(sql)
```

giving:

```
    Type Value
1 TEN_02     5
2 TEN_04     8
3 TEN_05     9
4 VIT_06     6
5 VIT_11     6
6 VIT_08     7
```

To see the resulting SQL statement after string interpolation:

```
fn$identity(sql)
## [1] "select * from df where substr(Type, 1, instr(Type, '_') - 1) in ('TEN','VIT')"
```

**2)** An alternative approach is to create a data frame from the types and join it to `df`:

```
TypeDF <- read.table(text = TYPES, sep = ",", as.is = TRUE, col.names = "Type")
sqldf("select d.* 
       from df d 
       join TypeDF t on substr(d.Type, 1, instr(d.Type, '_') - 1) = t.Type")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a compound condition (an `OR` condition) like

```
SELECT * FROM df
WHERE Type LIKE 'TEN%'
OR Type LIKE 'VIT%'
```

have no idea about `sqldf` but think you can do it like below per this blog https://codywu2010.wordpress.com/2015/08/08/r-sqldf-select-with-condition-of-one-column-like-another-column/

```
df1 <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df WHERE Type LIKE TYPES || '%' ")
```

Comment: I could use this but I want to use a variable "TYPES" because my list can grow and I would just want to pass in using a variable rather than list it out in the sql statement.